# Cannot get this menu to show horizontal

Tags: html, css, navbar

I can't get this menu to show horizontal, I want it to show like the one on  w3Schools (enter their page, and above, in the navbar there is an option with "MORE", so when you click it, it shows a big menu with many a lot of options.)

The CSS is the simple Bootstrap default one.

I can't get mine to do so. Here is the code I'm using:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Extra Verification <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Provides Address, Status, Previous Names</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.concord-sots.ct.gov/CONCORD/online?sn=InquiryServlet&eid=99" target="myIframe">Connecticut</a> </li>
    <li><a href="https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/BusinessSearch" target="myIframe">Georgia</a> </li>
    <li><a href="https://coraweb.sos.la.gov/CommercialSearch/CommercialSearch.aspx" target="myIframe">Louisiana</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.vtsosonline.com/online/BusinessInquire/" target="myIframe">Vermont</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://portal.sos.state.nm.us/corps/(S(avf1z0n02vbhx0turlfhca01))/Corplookup/Lookdn.aspx" target="myIframe">New Mexico</a></li>

    <li class="divider"></li>

    <li class="dropdown-header">Provides Address and Status</li>
    <li><a href="http://arc-sos.state.al.us/CGI/CORPNAME.MBR/INPUT">Alabama</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.commerce.alaska.gov/CBP/Main/CBPLSearch.aspx?mode=Corp">Alaska</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sos.arkansas.gov/corps/search_all.php">Arkansas</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ecorp.azcc.gov/Search">Arizona</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/">California</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sos.state.co.us/biz/BusinessEntityCriteriaExt.do">Colorado</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://hbe.ehawaii.gov/documents/search.html?zmobile=N&site_preference=normal">Hawaii</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.accessidaho.org/public/sos/corp/search.html?ScriptForm.startstep=crit">Idaho</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://charter.dat.maryland.gov/Pages/CharterSearch/default.aspx">Maryland</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want the dropdowns to appear/disappear on click? You need jQuery to do that. With CSS you can make them appear/disappear on hover but not toggle on clicking.

Comment: you have to include the css and javascript links in your head section, look at this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript into your page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Extra Verification
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Provides Address, Status, Previous Names</li>
      <li><a href="http://www.concord-sots.ct.gov/CONCORD/online?sn=InquiryServlet&eid=99" target="myIframe">Connecticut</a> </li>
      <li><a href="https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/BusinessSearch" target="myIframe">Georgia</a> </li>
      <li><a href="https://coraweb.sos.la.gov/CommercialSearch/CommercialSearch.aspx" target="myIframe">Louisiana</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.vtsosonline.com/online/BusinessInquire/" target="myIframe">Vermont</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://portal.sos.state.nm.us/corps/(S(avf1z0n02vbhx0turlfhca01))/Corplookup/Lookdn.aspx" target="myIframe">New Mexico</a></li>

      <li class="divider"></li>

      <li class="dropdown-header">Provides Address and Status</li>
      <li><a href="http://arc-sos.state.al.us/CGI/CORPNAME.MBR/INPUT">Alabama</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.commerce.alaska.gov/CBP/Main/CBPLSearch.aspx?mode=Corp">Alaska</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.sos.arkansas.gov/corps/search_all.php">Arkansas</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://ecorp.azcc.gov/Search">Arizona</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/">California</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.sos.state.co.us/biz/BusinessEntityCriteriaExt.do">Colorado</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://hbe.ehawaii.gov/documents/search.html?zmobile=N&site_preference=normal">Hawaii</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.accessidaho.org/public/sos/corp/search.html?ScriptForm.startstep=crit">Idaho</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://charter.dat.maryland.gov/Pages/CharterSearch/default.aspx">Maryland</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```